# insert if a field value doesn't exist without using ignore,unique

Tags: php, mysql

how can insert a record if only a specific value doesn't exist in a field

```
  INSERT INTO `users` (fb_id, username) 
    SELECT '.$id_signed_in.', '.$user_signed_in.' FROM `users` 
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` 
                      WHERE fb_id='.$id_signed_in.') 
    LIMIT 1'
```

this does not seem to work

Comment: create `UNIQUE` index on `fb_id`, it will automatic prevent duplicate entry

Comment: why not using unique or insert ignore?

Comment: @ajreal it gives me an error when setting the field `fb_id` to unique.

Comment: it gives me this error: `MySQL said: 

#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this ,

```
INSERT INTO `users` (fb_id, username) 
SELECT '.$id_signed_in.', '.$user_signed_in.' FROM `users` 
WHERE fb_id NOT IN(SELECT fb_id FROM `users` 
                  WHERE fb_id='.$id_signed_in.') 
LIMIT 1'
```

Comment: I should have added quotes around $user_signed_in . it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

If you want a field to be unique, set it as unique and delete duplicate entries if exists.

You can use

```
insert ignore into users (fb_id, username) values ('$id_signed_in','$user_signed_in')
```

Here you have to set fb_id as unique to prevent duplicate entries. It only inserts, if fb_id doesn't exists in the db.

Another way without using ignore, unique :

```
$res = mysql_query("select id from users where fb_id='$id_signed_in'");
if(!(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)){
    mysql_query("insert into users (fb_id, username) values ('$id_signed_in','$user_signed_in')");
}
```